# Critique my proof of $\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert \leq \lvert x + y \rvert + \lvert x - y \rvert, \ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: solution-verification

Critique my proof of $\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert \leq \lvert x + y \rvert + \lvert x - y \rvert, \ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Case #1: $x = y$**

$\Rightarrow \lvert x \rvert = \lvert y \rvert$. Hence,
$$\lvert x + y \rvert = \lvert x \rvert + \lvert x \rvert = 2 \lvert x \rvert$$
and $$\lvert x - y \rvert = \lvert x - x\rvert = 0.$$
Thus, $\lvert x \rvert$ + $\lvert y \rvert = 2 \lvert x \rvert \leq \lvert x + y \rvert + \lvert x - y \rvert = 2 \lvert x \rvert$.

**Case #2: $x > y$**

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert > \lvert x + y \rvert + \lvert x - y \rvert.$
Hence, $$ \lvert x + y \rvert + \lvert x - y \rvert < \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert$$
$$\leq \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert + \lvert x - y \rvert < \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert$$
by the triangle inequality, which is a contradiction b/c $\lvert x - y \rvert > 0$. Thus, it must be that $\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert \leq \lvert x + y \rvert + \lvert x - y \rvert$ in this case.

**Case #3: $x < y$**

WLOG, the proof is the same as case #2.

$\therefore \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert \leq \lvert x + y \rvert + \lvert x - y \rvert, \ x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Assume for the sake of contradiction. I'll edit the post so that it's more clear.

Comment: Agreed with @AnneBauval, the second line in your case 2 does not follow from the first line. (If $A < B$ and $A \le C$ we cannot conclude necessarily that $C < B$.)

Comment: The sources that I'm using say that $\lvert x + y \rvert  \leq \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert$. Did I make some logical leap? https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Cc7PeuDa2Zo/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: How did you get $|x|+|y|+|x-y| < |x|+|y|$ by the triangle inequality? If I'm seeing what you mean, shouldn't you have $|x-y| < |x|+|y|$ so that $|x|+|y|+|x-y| < 2|x|+2|y|$? Also, while I understand why you're trying to use those particular cases, you're going to have to bifurcate into cases such as $y>0, x<0$ eventually as well because $|y|,|x|$ etc. are involved. If you don't want to do that, you'll probably need intermediate points such as $\frac{x+y}{2}, \frac{x-y}{2}$ etc. to use with the original triangle inequality.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer the didn't get $|x|+|y| + |x-y| < |x| +|y|$ by the triangle inequality.  They got $|x+y| + |x-y| \le |x| + |y| + |x-y|$ by the T.I and $|x+y| + |x-y| < |x| + |y|$ by assumption but... as others have pointed out.  Showing that $A \le C$ bt triangle equality and $A< B$ by assumption, one can not conclude $B < C$.  So this prove isn't valid.

Comment: @fleablood I see, yeah, that looks like the mistake.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality to sho $|x+y| + |x-y| \le |x+y + x-y| = 2|x|$ and $|x+y| + |x-y| = |x+y| +|y-x| \le |x+y+y-x| = 2|y|$ and that $2\min(|x|, |y|) \le |x| + |y| \le 2\max(|x|,|y| \le |x+y| + |x-y|$.

Comment: This is the cutest way to do it:  $|x|+|y| =\frac 12(|2x| + |2y|)=\frac 12(|x+y+x-y|+|x+y+y-x|)\le \frac 12(|x+y| + |x-y| + |x+y|+|y-x|)=\frac 12(2(|x+y| + |x-y|))=|x+y| + |x-y|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a flaw in your case 2 because you used the triangle inequality the wrong way. $|x + y|+|x - y|<blah$ and $|x + y|\le|x|+|y|$ don't imply
$|x|+|y|+|x - y|<blah.$

Comment: @FaithAlone: $\lvert 2 + (-1)\rvert + \lvert 2-(-1) \rvert < 4.5$ and yet $\lvert 2 \rvert + \lvert -1 \rvert + \lvert 2-(-1) \rvert$ is not $< 4.5$.

Comment: @Torsten Thanks!

Comment: I get the concept, but in your example $\left|2\right|+\left|-1\right|+\left|2-\left(-1\right)\right| > \lvert 2 \rvert + \lvert -1 \rvert$, which still works for my contradiction proof. I've really got myself in a rabbit hole lol.

Comment: Of course I cannot produce an example where the statement in your title is wrong; because that statement is true. It is just that your proof does not work, and the example shows why one conclusion in your proof, the one Anne Bauval  states here, fails.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, there is a mistake because from the inequalities

$$\begin{cases}|x+y|+|x-y|<|x|+|y|\\|x+y|\leqslant|x|+|y|\end{cases}$$

you cannot deduce that

$$|x|+|y|+|x-y|<|x|+|y|\;.$$

Indeed, $\,A+B<C+D\,$ and $\,A\leqslant C+D\,$ do **not** imply that $\,C+D+B<C+D\,.$

For example, if $\,A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4\,,\,$ then $\,A+B<C+D\,$ and $\,A<C+D\;\;$ **but** $\,C+D+B\not\lt C+D\,.$

---

**Addendum 1:**

You could prove the property in the following way.

If $\,x\geqslant0\,$ and $\,y\geqslant0\,,\,$ then
$|x|+|y|=x+y=|x+y|\leqslant|x+y|+|x-y|\,.$

If $\,x<0\,$ and $\,y<0\,,\,$ then
$|x|+|y|=-x-y=-(x\!+\!y)=|x+y|\leqslant|x+y|+|x-y|\,.$

If $\,x\geqslant0\,$ and $\,y<0\,,\,$ then
$|x|+|y|=x-y=|x-y|\leqslant|x+y|+|x-y|\,.$

If $\,x<0\,$ and $\,y\geqslant0\,,\,$ then
$|x|+|y|=-x+y=-(x\!-\!y)=|x-y|\leqslant|x+y|+|x-y|\,.$

---

**Addendum 2:**

A better way to prove the property is the following one.

$\begin{align}|x|+|y|&=\left|\dfrac{(x+y)+(x-y)}2\right|+\left|\dfrac{(x+y)-(x-y)}2\right|\leqslant\\&\leqslant\dfrac{|x+y|+|x-y|}2+\dfrac{|x+y|+|x-y|}2=\\&=|x+y|+|x-y|\;.\end{align}$

Comment: Why have you downvoted my answer ? Is there any mistake ?

Comment: I didn't read it. The question was "review my proof", not "how to prove".

Comment: No, I won't. If you want a proof review, ask for it in a separate post. As explained above, your "answer" is not an answer to this post.

Comment: you are being downvoted because you are not answering the question. You need to critique OP's prove, not hastily post your own solution just to get some internet points.

Comment: @Invisible, it is the first case.

Comment: I have critiqued OP’s proof. Please, could you remove your downvotes ?

Comment: I understand that I can't deduce $\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert + \lvert x -  y \rvert < \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert$, but keep in mind that case #2 is a contradiction proof. I'm using that result to prove that there is a contradiction.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, because $|x-y|\geqslant0$.

Comment: @FaithAlone, you cannot deduce it because $\,A+B<C+D\,$ and $\,A\leqslant C+D\,$ do **not** imply that $\,C+D+B<C+D\,.$
For example, if $\,A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4\,,\,$ then $\,A+B<C+D\,$ and $\,A<C+D\;\;$ **but** $\,C+D+B\not\lt C+D\,.$